# How to run shim from inside grub2 code?

Tags: ubuntu, bootloader, uefi, grub2

I am new to grub. I am trying to enable UEFI secure boot from grub. I have decided to use shim to verify kernel's signature. Grub can be verified from UEFI.

I have pulled patches from Ubuntu's grub git repository. Grub uses `grub_efi_locate_protocol()` function to locate shim, currently it is not able to find shim and returns `NULL`.

I have following queries:

1. Where should I place `shim.efi` binary (I have placed it /boot partition)
2. Where does `grub_efi_system_table` variable get populated, and how is it used by `grub_efi_locate_protocol`?

Thanks

Comment: Holy sh--t... A question tagged with `grub` that's actually about programming and development. This is a diamond in the rough, and I think we  should nurture it. Can you provide some of the code around `grub_efi_locate_protocol` and `grub_efi_system_table`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue. When shim is executed, it installs shim protocol. Shim protocol is installed only when secure boot is enabled. I was trying to use the shim protocol with no secure boot, so, grub was unable to find shim protocol. A complete explanation of shim is here 
https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/19448.html